# Issue with array manipulation and memset

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I have a C program which reads characters from stdin (using getchar) until a blank line is read, and then a NULL element is added and all characters read before the blank line get sent to execve. Then, more characters are read and added to the same array (which I'm trying to reset after the first call to execve) until another blank line is read, and then that second section should be executed. I am having trouble using memset to reset the array after each call to execve and also working with the args[i] = NULL so that I can pass my array to execve.

e.g. usage:

echo

hello

*after seeing blank line it executes "echo hello"*

cat

goodbye

*should cat file "goodbye" but when the first two arguments are actually "echo" and "NULL"

```
int main()
{
  int pid, status, c, size = 10, length = 0, i, blankflag = 0, alrdyexec = 0;
  char argument[1000];
  char **args;
  char *token;
  args = (char**)malloc(size);
  extern int process(char **args);
  fflush(stdout);

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (length == size) {
        size += 10;
        args = realloc(args, size);
    }
    if (c != '\n') {
        argument[length++] = c;
        blankflag = 0;
        alrdyexec = 0;
    } else if ((c == '\n') && (blankflag == 0)) {
        blankflag = 1;
        argument[length++] = c;
    } else if ((c == '\n') && (blankflag == 1) && (alrdyexec == 0)) {
        alrdyexec = 1;
        i = 0;
        memset(args, 0, sizeof(args));
        token = strtok(argument, "\n");
        while (token != NULL) {
            args[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
            i++;
        }
        args[i] = NULL;
        // here it executes a function which runs execve
        }
        }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: sizeof(args) is just the size of the pointer, typically 4 or 8 bytes. So memset() probably clears fewer bytes than you expect it to.

Comment: PS: The call to malloc() and realloc() has the same problem (and is broken in other ways too. Always test for errors)

Comment: Why would you need to use `memset()` for your purpose?  On the second time through, just start back at the beginning of the buffer.  Whatever you wrote there with `memset()` would just be overwritten with the new data anyway, up to and including the terminator you write, and nothing past that matters.

Comment: In addition to Bjorn's comment, your test case has more than one line of input, and each line will be read into `argument`, and overwrite the previous line.  `args[i]` then stores results from `strtok()` which will be pointers to elements of `argument` - the result is that only the last element of `args` will be what you expect.

Comment: John, would it suffice to set the length back to 0 after executing the first command? What happens if the second command (e.g. 8 characters) is shorter than the first command (11 characters)? Won't the array then contain 8 characters from the second command (overwriting what was in the array before the second command) and the last 3 from the first characters?

Comment: You are aware the at the members of the `exec*()`-family of functions in case of success never return, aren't you?